# Nullable Decimal If Is Always True

Tags: razor, nullable, invalidoperationexception

I have a page that lists items within a Work Order. Each of these items has many properties, and an optional property of a discount. If there are no discounts on the Work Order we want to hide the column, and if there is we must show it for the lines that have a value.

The values are pulled from a database, and the Discount is a nullable decimal column which is pulled into a nullable decimal.

In the controller I check to see if there are any discounts and set a boolean called NoDiscount in the ViewBag.

The *ViewBag.NoDiscount == false* check is honored, but if it is true and the *item.Discount.HasValue* check is tested, it always returns true.

```
@if (ViewBag.NoDiscount == false) {
    <div class="col-xs-2" style="border-top: solid 1px #DDD;">
        if (@item.Discount.HasValue) {
        @item.Discount.Value.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ViewBag.Currency))
        }
    </div>
}
```

If I break the code and test if Discount.HasValue on null items, it returns false, yet the code continues on.

The error I get is:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Nullable object must have a value.
```

Comment: Are you using `dynamic` somewhere (apart from the `ViewBag`)? That can mess with code like this. Can you show the definition of `item` (and its type - you don't have to include all the fields and properties and what not, just the `class` bits and `Discount`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An hour looking at it before I ask, then I solve it myself 5 minutes after asking.

My @'s were in the wrong place.

```
@if (ViewBag.NoDiscount == false) {
<div class="col-xs-2" style="border-top: solid 1px #DDD;">
    @if (item.Discount.HasValue) {
    @item.Discount.Value.ToString("C", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ViewBag.Currency))
    }
</div>
}
```